# Facing issue while configuring git repo

Tags: git, gitlab, git-push

I am trying to push a repository to gitlab via command line and while doing that git is asking for git's password.

I did not set any password while configuring git. Tried giving gitlab password also but it is saying permission denied.

Please tell what to do.

Below is the code snippet of the error:

[image: The error]

Comment: What is your exact command and what does `git remote -v` output?

Comment: Hi, Below is the output of git remote -v command.                                  
origin  git@my-ip:Administrator/project1.git (fetch)
origin  git@my-ip:Administrator/project1.git (push)  and i tried pushing the code using git push command.

Comment: using gitlab docker image. and have already uploaded the ssh key to gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote is setup to use the SSH-URL.
This always uses the user `git` and you have to authenticate with your SSH certificate.
You have to have your SSH certificate uploaded to your account in GitLab for this to work.

If you don't want to use SSH certificate for authentication, you have to use the HTTPS remote URL instead.

Comment: If you uploaded your key, then you are not using your key or it would have worked. Try doing `ssh git@your-gitlab-server`. If everything is setup correctly your login will succeed and tell you as whom you authenticated. If it doesn't work, then you have not everything setup correctly. You can also add `-v`, `-vv` or `-vvv` to the `ssh` command, to enable debug output.

Comment: i uploaded this key on gitlab and again tried pushing the image to gitlab but again it asked for git's password and incorrect password and permission denied error were thrown.

Comment: i logged in also to the server using ssh and it logged in correctly

Comment: correctly means it entered into the server and i was able to access, manipulate the files which were stored in that server.

Comment: That means it was not correct. Correct would be a message from GitLab server like "you are authenticated as foo, there is no interactive shell access".

Comment: Did you maybe forget the username `git`?